# Why Scala can't compile function chains with a mix of spaces and dots?

Tags: scala, compilation

This compiles:

```
paragraphs.map { a =>

}.filter { b =>

}.map { c =>

}.sortBy { d =>

}.reverse
```

So does this:

```
paragraphs map { a =>

} filter { b =>

} map { c =>

} sortBy { d =>

} reverse // <- warning about postfix notation
```

But this does not (can't resolve variables inside sortBy):

```
paragraphs map { a =>

} filter { b =>

} map { c =>

} sortBy { d =>

}.reverse
```

Is it operator precedence? If so what are the reasons to prefer one version over the other?

Comment: Please post [minimum working examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example) in your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dot takes precedence, so what it's getting is sort of:

```
(1 to 5) map { a => a } filter ({ b => true }.reverse)
<console>:11: error: missing parameter type
           (1 to 5) map { a => a } filter ({ b => true }.reverse)
                                             ^
```

And `{b => true}` doesn't have a method `reverse`.  Technically `{b => true}` isn't even a valid expression, but you can make it a valid `PartialFunction` by specifying the expected type of `b`, thus giving you a more useful error message:

```
(1 to 5) map { a => a } filter { b: Int => true }.reverse
<console>:11: error: value reverse is not a member of Int => Boolean
           (1 to 5) map { a => a } filter { b: Int => true }.reverse
                                                             ^
```

Note, however, that postfix operators (ie, without dots) are now dis-recommended, and you get a warning if you try to use them:

```
~$ scala -feature
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_79).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> (1 to 5) map { a => a } filter { b => true } reverse
<console>:11: warning: postfix operator reverse should be enabled
by making the implicit value scala.language.postfixOps visible.
This can be achieved by adding the import clause 'import scala.language.postfixOps'
or by setting the compiler option -language:postfixOps.
See the Scala docs for value scala.language.postfixOps for a discussion
why the feature should be explicitly enabled.
       (1 to 5) map { a => a } filter { b => true } reverse
```

Comment: Slight clarification: "postfix operators (ie, without dots)" should be "without dots and arguments". The compiler wants about `reverse`, but the `(1 to 5) map { a => a } filter { b => true }` is fine.